# Displaying a dialog resource from a different DLL in MFC application

Tags: winapi, dll, mfc, embedded-resource

I have a Win32 resource DLL (No MFC), which has a dialog in it.

I can load the Win32 dll using `LoadLibrary` from the MFC application.

After loading the DLL, how do I bring up the dialog to show it to the user?

I Would appreciate if someone can share the code to do this.

I remember using [AfxGetResourceHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8ws31ff%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to do this kind of stuff, but don't remember it now.

Answer (score 1):

The basic steps are:

1. `LoadLibrary` (as you have done)
2. `FindResource` (gives you an HRSRC)
3. `LoadResource` (gives you an HGLOBAL)
4. `LockResource` (gives you an LPVOID which you can cast to LPCDLGTEMPLATE)
5. `CreateDialogIndirectParam` (creates the dialog)

Comment: Yes, and that sequence of functions is how you get it out of the DLL and display it.