# Display "Camera Controls" dialog from vfwwdm32.dll

Tags: winapi, dll, dialog, webcam, webcam-capture

I'm developing a webcam application and would like to re-use what looks to be standard dialog boxes for camera controls (those that configure webcam settings, like brightness, zoom, flicker compensation, etc). After some digging around I have identified that the necessary dialog resources are in the **vfwwdm32.dll**, dialog box *ID*s being `102` and `405`. Yes, that is a DLL that is for the ancient *Video For Windows* circa 1992.

The dialog resources are accessible via *DirectShow* as described in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375484(v=vs.85).aspx) using the interface provided by [IAMVfwCaptureDialogs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375983(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

Question #1:
Am I going about it the wrong way? If there's another (more modern) implementation of these dialog boxes available in Windows that I should be using?
I would like to avoid re-implementing these using the "preferred" method of building my own GUI by querying the available controls from the *WDM* itself and instead just use the dialog boxes that are already built by MS. Especially since they suit my needs quite nicely.

---

Question #2 (the main one):
Given that my application is not *DirectShow*-based (it is an *MS Media Foundation*-based) I'd like to not depend on the *DirectShow* legacy. That means I use the method described in [Displaying a dialog resource from...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500136/displaying-a-dialog-resource-from-a-different-dll-in-mfc-application) which basically boils down to `LoadLibrary()`->`FindResource()`->`LoadResource()`->`LockResource()`->`CreateDialogIndirectParam()`.

The problem I'm having is that the dialog box needs to know **which camera to control**. That, presumably, is done via an input parameter to the dialog box (I'm using that term loosely as it is not really a function but a *dialog data exchange* process).

How do I provide the necessary information to the dialog for it to properly work with the camera of my choice?

More generally: *how to implement data exchange with that dialog box?*

Comment: Doing the `CreateDialogIndirect()` method will still require you to write the dialog logic yourself; you'll be responsible for all the logic of that dialog, unless the dialog procedure is also exported.

Comment: So the `IAMVfwCaptureDialogs` route via *DirectShow* is the only way? :(

Comment: Since you are dealing with the old [Video For Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757708.aspx) technology, you might be looking for the `AVICap` API ([`capCreateCaptureWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756879.aspx),  [`capDlgVideoFormat()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756882.aspx), [`capDlgVideoDisplay()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756881.aspx), etc). See [Displaying Dialog Boxes to Set Video Characteristics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd797890.aspx).

Comment: I think I was not clear enough, but I am **not dealing with VFW**. I'm dealing with **MS Media Foundation** and trying to avoid using the *DirectShow* path.

Comment: Hi, I think that should try another way - try work with the driver of the selected camera device directly via `DeviceIoControl` on site - [USB Video Class Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/stream/usb-video-class-properties). It allows to change settings of camera like settings of device (camera IS DEVICE). It does not have User dialog window - as a result, you will need write your own GUI, but you can change options on the level of code. By the way - you must use `SymbolicLink` of camera for `DeviceIoControl` - camera IS DEVICE.

Comment: Writing my own GUI is **exactly** what I'm trying to avoid in here. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: I have read your question and I just suggest try. If you would not like write your own GUI - you can find already workable solution - open GitHub, and try find code with calling of KSPROPERTY - for example 'KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_EXPOSURE'. You wrote - 'I'd like to not depend on the DirectShow legacy', but you try use earlier generation - 'that is a DLL that is for the ancient Video For Windows circa 1992'.

Comment: Evgeny, the reason I'm trying to find a system-provided dialog box is to avoid unnecessary work. Yes, I could implement my own GUI, I could find an already built solution (OpenCV is a good example of a huge bloat), I could write it in HTML5 and load into an HTML-based dialog... I could do many things - that is not the point of the question. The point is: is there a way to re-use what is already in the system and if so: "How?".
Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to reuse the dialog boxes - you are only supposed to consume them using API.

Then if your primary API to deal with video capture hardware is Media Foundation, then this UI is simply not applicable. The UI belongs to Video for Windows and you can also consume it - in limited extent - from DirectShow when you are capturing video in DirectShow using legacy VFW capture filter.

Media Foundation can use the same hardware but it talks to it at a lower level point and VFW dialogs do not apply.

You are supposed to provide your own UI, which communicates to the device using Media Foundation interfaces. And there is absolutely no reason why you would want to use the dialog templates from VFW DLL.

Comment: What is it that makes "this UI is simply not applicable" if I deal with MF? A camera control is a camera control. Open any app (Skype, Debut, AmCap...) - they **all** run this dialog box. In fact I'm yet to find a webcam app that *does NOT* do that. Could you elaborate on your assertion?
Keep in mind that I'm only interested in one dialog of the 3 provided - the other 2 indeed only apply to VFW by design as they deal with the H/W selection and video capture format settings.

Comment: Specifically Camera Control property page might work with a Media Foundation source if you [query `IAMCameraControl`](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/05/19/windows-media-foundation-controlling-camera-properties/) and display a standard COM/OLE property frame dialog API [`OleCreatePropertyFrame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678437) with a CLSID `{71F96465-78F3-11D0-A18C-00A0C9118956}` AKA `CLSID_CameraControlPropertyPage`. This might work but remember it is an undocumented mix of APIs.

Comment: This is a very interesting idea indeed. Feels very hacky though, TBH.